# In copyWithZone:, should I use zone for all allocs or just for the returned object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject<NSCopying> {
    SomeOtherClass *obj;
}
```

In the definition of copyWithZone:, I do this:

```
SomeClass *someCopy = [[SomeClass allocWithZone:zone] init];
```

So my question is, if I want to make a copy of obj, which of these is correct/recommended?

option A:

```
objCopy = [obj copyWithZone:zone];
```

option B:

```
objCopy = [obj copy];
```

Comment: Or Option C:

objCopy = [obj copyWithZone:[self zone]];

So that the copy will be allocated in the same zone as the caller. But then again that is if you use zones in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using reference-counted memory management (not Garbage Collection) you should use `[obj copyWithZone:zone]`. In addition, you should (in the same circumstances) use `+allocWithZone:` instead of `+alloc` to allocate the copies. This allocates memory for the instances in a specified memory zone (see NSZone). Developers might use a separate zone if they are going to allocate *many* objects which will be no longer needed at roughly the same time. The entire zone can then be reclaimed in one operation with `NSRecylceZone`, helping to prevent memory fragmentation. In general, using a private zone is not needed (and will generally hurt performance; profile your code!). Assuming the developer wants a copy in a particular zone, I think you would assume they would want all related instances in the same zone.

The `-copy` and `+alloc` methods call the `-copyWithZone:` and `+allocWithZone:` methods respectively, passing the default zone.

Comment: Is there any particular reason--what's going on under the hood?

Comment: A zone is an area from which you allocate memory. The idea is that you can make a whole bunch of related allocations (Cocoa objects, buffers, etc.) from one zone, then free the zone instead of all the objects in it. In practice, I hear, this doesn't really gain you much.